# Errors during make test installing kibana via homebrew on Mac (xcode issue?)

Tags: xcode, homebrew, kibana, osx-elcapitan

Hi I'm trying to install kibana but it's erroring. I've used kibana to install elasticsearch fine.
Here's the end of my install with verbose, followed by an xcode error that I see further up that may be the problem:

==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/homebrew
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.11
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/homebrew/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

```
Error: kibana 5.1.2 did not build
Logs:
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/00.options.out
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/01.configure
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/01.configure.cc
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/02.make
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/02.make.cc
     /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kibana/build.sandbox.log


xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Do I really need the full xcode suite install for Kibana to work?